# Import 1 column of csv, replace string, then join each row into one row with values surrounded in quotes

Tags: powershell, csv

Im using powershell and I have a csv file that has a ton of data but the only field I am concerned with is the first one.

I need to:

1. Extract the first column of data with the header: ******Ticket_ID******
2. Remove a trailing string from the values in this column (site:)
3. Join all of the values in the column into a single, space delimited row, but ensure each value retains the double quotes wrapping each of them.
4. Prepend this row with a long string and write it to a file. (I havent tried to tackle this part yet because I cant get 1-3 to work fully.)

**I have tried several permutations of this code:**

```
    $TT = (Import-Csv '.\sourcefile.csv').______Ticket_ID______ -join (" ")
    $TT = $TT -replace 'site:',''
    $TT | Set-Content -Path .\JulyTickets.csv
```

**Example of my csv:**

```
"______Ticket_ID______","____________Title____________","___________CreateDate___________"
"site:TICKET1","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET2","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET3","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET4","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET5","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
```

**My frustrations:**
If I use Export-CSV the resulting csv only contains the character length of the values.

If I use Set-Content, I can successfully extract the first column, and remove the leading string (site:), join all of the rows into a single row, and write this out to a file but it does not retain the double quotes around each of the values in the csv ("site:TICKET1"). And the output looks like this:

`TICKET1 TICKET2 TICKET3 TICKET4 TICKET5`

I'm not sure if I'm doing things out of order here, or if I'm missing something but I'm unable to get both the values inline, and individually surrounded in quotes.

**Required Output:**

`this is a long string that needs to be prepended to the data "TICKET1" "TICKET2" "TICKET3" "TICKET4" "TICKET5"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. The need for pipes and PowerShell's Calculated Properties expression in the end is to overcome powershell removing double quotes

```
$string = 'this is a long string that needs to be prepended to the data ' + (Get-Content -Path \.sourcefile.csv | Convertfrom-Csv -Delimiter "," | select ______Ticket_ID______ -ExpandProperty ______Ticket_ID______ | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'site:', '';} | select @{ Name = 'Ticket';  Expression = {$([char]34) + $_ + $([char]34)}} | Select Ticket -ExpandProperty Ticket);
write-host $string
```

returns

```
this is a long string that needs to be prepended to the data "TICKET1" "TICKET2" "TICKET3" "TICKET4" "TICKET5"
```

Comment: Yup this works. But now ive run into another issue I'll have to solve, and thats in the data in my sourcefile. it seems as though a few of the entries have line breaks in some of the later fields which is populating the _______TICKET_ID________ field with more than just the ticket numbers. I'll have to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, I'm using the `-Header` argument since the only needed column is the first one.

```
$csv = @'
"______Ticket_ID______","____________Title____________","___________CreateDate___________"
"site:TICKET1","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET2","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET3","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET4","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
"site:TICKET5","SOMETITLE","01/01/1901"
'@ |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header ID |
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
ForEach-Object {
    '"{0}"' -f $_.ID.TrimStart('site:')
}

$toPrepend = 'this is a long string that needs to be prepended to the data'

"$toPrepend $($csv -join ' ')"

# Above yields => this is a long string that needs to be prepended to the data "TICKET1" "TICKET2" "TICKET3" "TICKET4" "TICKET5"
```

Note, I'm only using `ConvertFrom-Csv` as an example here but in your case, it should look like this:

```
$TT = Import-Csv '.\sourcefile.csv' -Header ID | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    '"{0}"' -f $_.ID.TrimStart('site:')
}

$toPrepend = 'this is a long string that needs to be prepended to the data'

"$toPrepend $($TT -join ' ')" | Out-File JulyTickets.csv # => Not sure why CSV here, since this is no longer a CSV
```

Comment: While it looks like this works, the other example seems much more simplified.